# MacBook using USB cable for connection

Tags: time-machine

Please I am using external devices with my Windows PC but I went to put it on my MacBook, so when I plug it in, it displays the storage as a Time Machine backup, then I mistakenly click on use it.

After that, it was trying to do something like installing, then I eject it back. So I insert the hard drive back into my HP laptop using Windows but I couldn't find my files again there, what can I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks so much,Please can I recover the file, do you have idea how I can recover the files because they are important files or can change back to external hard drive to work with windows so that I can recover the files please help me

Answer (score 2):

If you let Time Machine backup to an external drive, this drive gets reformatted as APFS. This means that any data which you stored on the drive while it was connected to your Windows PC is lost.

Comment: Thanks so much,Please can I recover the file, do you have idea how I can recover the files because they are important files or can change back to external hard drive to work with windows so that I can recover the files please help me

Comment: @ola Windows File Recovery is beyond the scope of this site, sorry.